# Android-SE Unanswered Questions Cleanup

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Currently, there are **960** [questions with no upvoted answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/unanswered) on the main site. Of those:

- around **800** are more than a month old.
- **710** have no answer at all.
- more than **400** questions are of score 0 or less.

Additionally, Android-SE has a **85%** answer rate which puts us squarely in the lowest percentile (around 70th place out of 84).

I hope I'm not alone thinking that something needs to be done to improve the situation. What other sites are doing:

- The guys over at TeX-SE hold regular ["Answer the Unanswered"](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/regular-lets-deal-with-unanswered-questions-chat-meetings) sessions that are quite structured and efficient. Questions are answered, deleted, merged etc. as necessary. The site manages to keep the unanswered volume around 200 regardless of the growth TeX-SE has experienced recently. I'd venture that something like 30-50 questions are dealt with in every session. See the [chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/conversation/answer-the-unanswered-session-1) to get an idea how it works.
- We do something similar on [Travel-SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com) -- there is a somewhat irregular ["Answer-a-thon"](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360/halloween-answer-a-thon) sessions that are scheduled a week or so in advance in chat.

I think we can do something similar on our own, depending on high-rep users and mods time constraints. I'd say a whole-day, drop-in session, held once per month in the weekend. I think we should be focusing most on the following:

- Closing old unanswered questions with weird device issues. Set some limit of say 2 months since last user intervention on the question. Decrease this for low-rep users that haven't visited the site for a long period -- say a month or so, or have only this one question. Reason for close would be most often "too localized".
- Finding duplicates, or creating artificially ones -- for example, hunting down OS upgrade information for devices we don't currently list in the "When will my device receive the X upgrade".

What do you guys think? Some further suggestions?

Comment: There are a lot of questions that seem valid but are very difficult to answer without having the same phone/issue.  I'd be hesitant to close these unless they're old and abandoned, as you note, but also I'd want to make sure that we have a consensus that that's the best thing to do.

Comment: I like the idea, but I also know that unanswered, un-upvoted questions like these are also auto-deleted after some time. I wouldn't to interfere with that. A crap question that no one is interested in deserves to be deleted.

Comment: @AlEverett Here are the exact criteria for automatic deletion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82408/.