# Old questions w/o answers and low view count

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, close-reasons

Every now and then, I run what I call a "housecleening task", walking the "unanswered" questions and see which I can answer, which are not answerable, and which might be closed. My actions are following these schema:

1. If I can provide an answer, I do so
2. If I think the question should be closed...

   1. ...and I have close-votes left, I vote-to-close
   2. ...otherwise I flag it for moderator attention, giving the corresponding reason
3. If I cannot answer the question, but maybe enhance it by a comment (asking for missing details and the like), I leave a comment
4. Everything else I "ignore"

This mental list I walk top-down, and break to the next question as soon as a condition was met (and the described action taken).

Currently, I'm stuck with some questions: I already v-c'd them in a previous run, so I cannot do that again. I marked some of them for moderator attention with the reason "too localized". For most of them, some mod found that reasonable. But for some I've got a "declined" with the comment: *Why? What reason is there for this to not be experienced by any other user?*

Unfortunately, there's no way to respond to the question -- so I decided to put it to Meta. In this special cases, the question would be:

**What makes a question "too localized?"**

But that would somehow be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/16575). The real question to me is:

**How useful is a question which is > 6 month old, having no answer (not even a hint in the comments) and a low view count (say, 10 views/month average)? How should we deal with those?**

There might of course be reasons why some other user could experience a similar problem. But with no answer, the question is not useful to him. It's quite frustrating if you are looking for a solution, and everywhere you see just the question, never an answer. I wouldn't even dare asking in such cases (what sense does it make? Nobody answered that question for a long time here, so why should they do so now?). Not being helpful, and even being discouraging, and due to the low view-count obviously not that interesting to readers makes them clear candidates to be closed (or even deleted) -- at least to me.

A comparable question is [What should happen to old unanswered questions where the OP didn't even care to check?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/16575), btw.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should work on a common policy that we all agree on about closing questions as "too localized". A new meta post with different suggestions about *when* a question is obviously of no use would surely help to find reasonable criteria.

Comment: Exactly. I recently notice someone is marking a lot of new questions (from the very same day) as "too localized" -- where there are not any access stats available, and the question itself *at least to me* does not appear to be "too localized". Clear "guidelines" would for sure be very helpful!

Comment: I\ll wait a few days and then create the meta question if there is no objection.

Comment: For the "new Meta post" you suggested, see: [What makes a question "too localized?"](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/16575) -- ooops, that was parallelized... Feel free to re-use the linked one (or close it then as duplicate, whatever).