# Is there a way to notify users of their new answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

I have seen that there are so many questions that has acceptable answers without the OP has not accepted. I have seen this issue has addressed to a *certain* extent in [some questions](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1250/23379). Yet, it is about unanswered questions.

So is there a way to notify users who have questions with no *accepted* answers to check their questions? If not (which I believe so), wouldn't it be better to implement a feature like that?

With that, they can either give their feedback or they can share if they have found an answer themselves. (this will help future users to get a certain or verified answer)

Comment: The OP of a question receives a global inbox notification for every answer posted. I don't know that doing anything beyond this would really be all that helpful, since it would feel more like pestering than anything else (or encourage people to accept answers that perhaps did not actually solve their problem).

Comment: I agree. If particular answer does not solve the problem, OP should at least give their feedback by way of a comment or so. That's the idea.

Comment: When a post has been migrated from one StackExchange site to another, then it is possible that the user has no account yet on that site. So that means that (s)he will not receive updates about this? Means no accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way currently is probably leaving a hint in a comment to the question, like

> Did any of the questions help solve you issue, so you could accept them? If not, what is missing?

This doesn't sound like "pestering", but rather concerned about the issue and its solution, as well as looking for improvement of the OP's situation.

Answer (score 3):

Accepting an answer is completely and entirely up to the asker of the question.  It should have no relevance to anyone else.

If you think a new user doesn't know about the acceptance feature — due to a comment like "thanks this was perfect" but no acceptance, for example — feel free to comment and give them a heads up.  Otherwise you shouldn't do anything.